# Azure DevOps Release not getting created with Continuous deployment trigger switched on

Tags: azure-devops

This morning we have experienced a strange thing when we found out the releases are not getting created after the successful build. I checked the Continuous deployment trigger which is also on as shown in the snapshot below. I don't remember making any changes to release definitions last week and it has affected all the release definitions. Has anyone else experienced this? What may be causing this? Is there any other switch that controls creation of release after the build.

[image]

Comment: This issue is being investigated by Microsoft.                                                             [Click here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/476277/vsts-build-not-triggering-release.html)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no other place which governs this behaviour. this should work fine, unless your build definition got deleted and recreated with new id (speculation)

Comment: I just had this happen, for some reason my build got deleted, so I re-created it with the same name.  My release then had to be re-associated with the new package, but it is no longer being triggered after the build has finished, even though the trigger is still enabled.  Is there a solution for this?

Comment: sorry, you should create a new question for this

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem today.
It has helped, to change this trigger to "disabled", save, change back to "enabled"

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue this morning, now fixed, where Releases were not being triggered. [Releases might not start after the build completes](https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/107732009)

Answer (score 0):

It was a Microsoft issue and its fixed now.